# Getting client ID in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to fix someone else's code and I have lines like this throughout my javascript -

```
var dataDiv = document.getElementById("ctl00_cpMain_tcMainTabs_tResBDetails_tcDetailTabs_tBDetail_bmrDetailDataDiv")
```

What is the preferred syntax?

FYI, this is a jQuery enabled web application.

Comment: My understanding is controls shouldn't be referenced in this manner, with the fully qualified name. Shouldn't I be able to reference bmrDetailDataDiv individually?

Comment: The ID is a bit lengthy but there is nothing to "fix"... it should work fine.

Comment: `var dataDiv = document.getElementById("<%= bmrDetailDataDiv.ClientID %>");`

Comment: I've been chastized here several times for referring to this naming convention. What if I were to change the name of one of the parent controls? What if Microsoft decides to name controls differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A trick we used to use but became redundant when we moved to MVC was something like this, easier when you use jquery as well

```
var datadiv = '#<%= bmrDetailDataDiv.ClientID %>'
```

Then you can call it using jquery as

```
$(datadiv)
```

or simplified if you don't need to use it anywhere else on the page is

```
$('#<%= bmrDetailDataDiv.ClientID %>')
```

you could use a match identifier but personally I don't think it is as elegant

```
$("div[id$='_bmrDetailDataDiv']");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going out on a limb and guessing this is an ASP.NET application? That looks like a server-side generated client ID.

You could try replacing it with something like:

```
var dataDiv = document.GetElementById("<%: [serverSideControlId].ClientID %>");
```

e.g.

```
var dataDiv = document.GetElementById("<%: Button1.ClientID %>");
```

or, if using jQuery:

```
var dataDiv = $("#<%: Button1.ClientID %>")[0];
```

Comment: Do I add var dataDiv = $("#<%: Button1.ClientID %>")[0]; directly in the javascript code?

Comment: I would guess so. As long as this javaScript is running on the same page upon which the control is found.